# How to convert this Recursive DP (Top Down) to Iterative DP (Bottom Up)

Tags: python-3.x

Please explain in general how to convert Top Down DP (recursive) to Bottom Up DP.

Problem Statement: Given an integer array nums, return the length of the longest strictly increasing subsequence.

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLIS(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        N = len(nums)
        prev = min(nums)-1
        m = min(nums)

        dp = [[-1 for i in range(min(nums)-1, max(nums)+2)] for j in range(N + 1)]

        def recurse(index, prev):
            if index == N:
                return 0
            if dp[index][prev-m] != -1:
                return dp[index][prev-m]

            if nums[index] > prev:
                dp[index][prev-m] = max(1 + recurse(index + 1, nums[index]), recurse(index + 1, prev))
                return dp[index][prev-m]
            else:
                dp[index][prev-m] =  recurse(index + 1, prev)
                return dp[index][prev-m]
        
        return recurse(0, prev)
```

I have tried the above solution but it says TLE. Would Top Down approach will help or is there any better approach to the problem.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  Did you read what the `dsa` tag is for?  Also, why did you tag this as `cp`?  Does this have to do with the `cp` command from Unix?

Comment: DP is a poor choice for this problem, because the runtime is `O(N * range(nums))`. Essentially, you include in DP the entirety of the range of the values in `nums`, whose count, according to the [constraints of the problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/), can be as big as 2 * 10^4. You need to go for a different method.

Comment: I don't believe there is such a thing as a general approach for converting a recursive solution to a Dynamic Programming solution, since any DP solution must be dependent on the problem constraints.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.